# How to get cookies value to set in requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am accessing a URL `https://streeteasy.com/sales/all` which does not show the page unless Cookie is set. I am having no idea how this cookie value being generated. I highly doubt that cookie value is fixed so I guess I can't use a hard-coded Cookie value either.

Code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'authority': 'streeteasy.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'referer': 'https://streeteasy.com/sales/all',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'D_SID=103.228.157.1:Bl5GGXCWIxq4AopS1Hkr7nkveq1nlhWXlD3PMrssGpU; _se_t=0944dfa5-bfb4-4085-812e-fa54d44acc54; google_one_tap=0; D_IID=AFB68ACC-B276-36C0-8718-13AB09A55E51; D_UID=23BA0A61-D0DF-383D-88A9-8CF65634135F; D_ZID=C0263FA4-96BF-3071-8318-56839798C38D; D_ZUID=C2322D79-7BDB-3E32-8620-059B1D352789; D_HID=CE522333-8B7B-3D76-B45A-731EB750DF4D; last_search_tab=sales; se%3Asearch%3Asales%3Astate=%7C%7C%7C%7C; streeteasy_site=nyc; se_rs=123%2C1029856%2C123%2C1172313%2C2815; se%3Asearch%3Ashared%3Astate=102%7C%7C%7C%7Cfalse; anon_searcher_stage=initial; se_login_trigger=4; se%3Abig_banner%3Asearch=%7B%22123%22%3A2%7D; se%3Abig_banner%3Ashown=true; se_lsa=2019-07-08+04%3A01%3A30+-0400; _ses=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%3D--d869dc53b8165c9f9e77233e78c568f610994ba7',
}
session = requests.Session()

response = session.get('https://streeteasy.com/for-sale/downtown', headers=headers, timeout=20)
if response.status_code == 200:
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    links = soup.select('h3 > a')
    print(links)
```

Comment: So what's the exact problem with that code?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov You see, the cookie is hard-coded. It needs to be dynamic because the cookie works for a while and then expire.

Comment: You copy-pasted that cookie from your browser, right?

Comment: @IvanVinogradov Yes Sir

Comment: I think this page is protected by distil

Comment: @QHarr It is for sure. The cookie is by Distil

Comment: @IvanVinogradov Anything I could do?